# Get the mean from Python dataframe based on index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which is a result from a `groupby`call

```
test=uniqueStudents.groupby(['index1','index2']).count()

test.head(10)
```

I am looking to get an aggregate where I find the mean of the count output across index1

the result and desired output are shown below

Current/Desired Ouput:

[image: Current/Desired Ouput]

Can somebody help me with the python code to achieve this? Or is there any other way I can get it from the dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `level` argument in the `groupby` method which can take the name of an index.

```
test.groupby(level='index1').mean()
```

Additionally, you can reset the index and do a normal groupby with the `by` argument.

```
test.reset_index().groupby('index1').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by level `index1` and aggregate [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and then get [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) by columns:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'column4': {('01-06-15', 278658): 22, ('01-06-15', 206905): 101, ('02-06-15', 225800): 308, ('02-06-15', 225596): 19, ('01-06-15', 152551): 64, ('01-06-15', 124337): 54, ('02-06-15', 235369): 7, ('01-06-15', 31883): 124, ('03-06-15', 124337): 17}, 'column10': {('01-06-15', 278658): 17.0, ('01-06-15', 206905): 60.0, ('02-06-15', 225800): 280.0, ('02-06-15', 225596): 15.0, ('01-06-15', 152551): 55.0, ('01-06-15', 124337): 21.0, ('02-06-15', 235369): 3.0, ('01-06-15', 31883): 62.0, ('03-06-15', 124337): np.nan}, 'column3': {('01-06-15', 278658): 22, ('01-06-15', 206905): 101, ('02-06-15', 225800): 308, ('02-06-15', 225596): 19, ('01-06-15', 152551): 64, ('01-06-15', 124337): 54, ('02-06-15', 235369): 7, ('01-06-15', 31883): 124, ('03-06-15', 124337): 17}, 'column8': {('01-06-15', 278658): 17.0, ('01-06-15', 206905): 60.0, ('02-06-15', 225800): 280.0, ('02-06-15', 225596): 15.0, ('01-06-15', 152551): 55.0, ('01-06-15', 124337): 21.0, ('02-06-15', 235369): 3.0, ('01-06-15', 31883): 62.0, ('03-06-15', 124337): np.nan}, 'column11': {('01-06-15', 278658): 22.0, ('01-06-15', 206905): 101.0, ('02-06-15', 225800): 308.0, ('02-06-15', 225596): 19.0, ('01-06-15', 152551): 64.0, ('01-06-15', 124337): 54.0, ('02-06-15', 235369): 7.0, ('01-06-15', 31883): 124.0, ('03-06-15', 124337): np.nan}, 'column5': {('01-06-15', 278658): 22, ('01-06-15', 206905): 101, ('02-06-15', 225800): 308, ('02-06-15', 225596): 19, ('01-06-15', 152551): 64, ('01-06-15', 124337): 54, ('02-06-15', 235369): 7, ('01-06-15', 31883): 124, ('03-06-15', 124337): 17}, 'column7': {('01-06-15', 278658): 22, ('01-06-15', 206905): 101, ('02-06-15', 225800): 308, ('02-06-15', 225596): 19, ('01-06-15', 152551): 64, ('01-06-15', 124337): 54, ('02-06-15', 235369): 3, ('01-06-15', 31883): 124, ('03-06-15', 124337): 17}, 'column2': {('01-06-15', 278658): 22, ('01-06-15', 206905): 101, ('02-06-15', 225800): 308, ('02-06-15', 225596): 19, ('01-06-15', 152551): 64, ('01-06-15', 124337): 54, ('02-06-15', 235369): 7, ('01-06-15', 31883): 124, ('03-06-15', 124337): 17}, 'column1': {('01-06-15', 278658): 22, ('01-06-15', 206905): 101, ('02-06-15', 225800): 308, ('02-06-15', 225596): 19, ('01-06-15', 152551): 64, ('01-06-15', 124337): 54, ('02-06-15', 235369): 7, ('01-06-15', 31883): 124, ('03-06-15', 124337): 17}, 'column6': {('01-06-15', 278658): 22, ('01-06-15', 206905): 101, ('02-06-15', 225800): 308, ('02-06-15', 225596): 19, ('01-06-15', 152551): 64, ('01-06-15', 124337): 54, ('02-06-15', 235369): 7, ('01-06-15', 31883): 124, ('03-06-15', 124337): 17}, 'column9': {('01-06-15', 278658): 17.0, ('01-06-15', 206905): 60.0, ('02-06-15', 225800): 280.0, ('02-06-15', 225596): 15.0, ('01-06-15', 152551): 55.0, ('01-06-15', 124337): 21.0, ('02-06-15', 235369): 3.0, ('01-06-15', 31883): 62.0, ('03-06-15', 124337): np.nan}})
test.index.names = ['index1','index2'] 
test = test[['column'+str(col) for col in range(1,12)]]
print (test)
                 column1  column2  column3  column4  column5  column6  \
index1   index2                                                         
01-06-15 31883       124      124      124      124      124      124   
         124337       54       54       54       54       54       54   
         152551       64       64       64       64       64       64   
         206905      101      101      101      101      101      101   
         278658       22       22       22       22       22       22   
02-06-15 225596       19       19       19       19       19       19   
         225800      308      308      308      308      308      308   
         235369        7        7        7        7        7        7   
03-06-15 124337       17       17       17       17       17       17   

                 column7  column8  column9  column10  column11  
index1   index2                                                 
01-06-15 31883       124     62.0     62.0      62.0     124.0  
         124337       54     21.0     21.0      21.0      54.0  
         152551       64     55.0     55.0      55.0      64.0  
         206905      101     60.0     60.0      60.0     101.0  
         278658       22     17.0     17.0      17.0      22.0  
02-06-15 225596       19     15.0     15.0      15.0      19.0  
         225800      308    280.0    280.0     280.0     308.0  
         235369        3      3.0      3.0       3.0       7.0  
03-06-15 124337       17      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
```

```
df = test.groupby(level='index1').mean().mean(axis=1).reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
     index1         val
0  01-06-15   57.818182
1  02-06-15  107.939394
2  03-06-15   17.000000
```

Another solution is first `mean` by columns and then `groupby`:

```
df = test.mean(axis=1).groupby(level='index1').mean().reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
     index1         val
0  01-06-15   57.818182
1  02-06-15  107.939394
2  03-06-15   17.000000
```